# First time working with nginx and unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have looked through the railscast for configuring nginx and unicorn. I have checked out nginx doc but still can't make heads to tail with what I should do to get nginx up and running. I have googled some tutorials which may not be relevant anymore.

Can someone give me a quick sense of how to get nginx and unicorn up and running?
point me to some resources, give me some steps?

Comment: you might want to checkout these chef scripts that automate most of the setup - http://teohm.github.io/blog/2013/04/17/chef-cookbooks-for-busy-ruby-developers/

Comment: railscast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/293-nginx-unicorn

Comment: @Vimsha that railscast is pretty outdated.